# How to make a single list of all the entities of an output of a loop

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Below is the code which returns a print out of 8 figures:

```
for i in range(A,A+30):
        for j in range(6,7):
            if "X" in str(sh1.cell(i,j).value):
                print(i)
```

Commandline Output:

```
44
55
57
61
65
69
71
72
```

How can I store these entities in their order in a single list like this:

```
["44", "55", "57", "61", "65", "69", "71", "72"]
```

Comment: Use `ws.iter_rows(values_only=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to create a new `list` and add the items to it:

```py
values = []
for i in range(A,A+30):
    for j in range(6,7):
        if "X" in str(sh1.cell(i,j).value):
            print(i)
            values.append(str(i))
```

values == `["44", "55", "57", "61", "65", "69", "71", "72"]`

Getting familiar with `list`s (and other basic python data structures) can get very handy: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists